# What is better: Interface or playing with public/protected?

Tags: java, coding-style, interface, public, protected

I have a class with 5 methods. 3 of these methods just have to be opened by other classes in the same package and 2 have to be opened by other classes in an other package.

as example:

```
void setTimeArray(int[] zeitArray) {
    this.timeArray = timeArray ;
}

public int[] getTimeArray() {
    return timeArray ;
}
```

now I was wondering what I should make:

- should I make the 3 methods `protected` and the 2 other `public`?
  or
- should I make an interface for the 2 methods?

so what would be cleaner and better for the performance of my application and why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem confused about the use of `public`, `protected`, etc.  The public methods in your class comprise the public interface of your class.  When you design your class, you decide what functionality you want to expose to consumers of your class.

You should only make methods protected IMO for polymorphism.  If you are making a method protected so that another class in the package can get at internals, etc., then it is probably a bad class design.  You should *not* make a method protected just because no other classes are using it *right now*.  If you need to use it from another class in the future, you'd have to change the class.

You shouldn't need to create an interface if there aren't multiple concrete classes implementing that interface.

The public interface of a class should flow pretty naturally if you get the OOP paradigm.  The decisions should involve more about *how* to expose function than *what* to expose.

Answer (score 2):

If there is a single "subject" that is common to the 2 methods but not to the other 3, consider splitting up the class into 2 different classes. If you do so, consider moving the class with the 2 methods to the package in which it will be used (if it makes sense in terms of the "subject" of that package).

In any case, use the lowest visibility that allows you to do what you wish to do.

Also, prefer default visibility to protected (the difference is that protected is like default, but also allows for subclasses in *different* packages to access those methods).

Comment: I have setter and getter and the other packages should only use the getter

Comment: @Neifen: Then just use visibility. Public getters, default setters.

Answer (score 2):

As the 3 methods of your class are access by the classes of the same package then no need to have a **protected** access modifier rather you can use **default**. **protected** should be used when you want your subclass to access the methods.

and about the **public** methods you can go for interface if you think you have a similar class which has these two methods implemented in it. so that through interface you can relate them.

Answer (score 1):

You should write the interface as soon as you think, that you might use or need it ;)

In addition to the interface: keeping the non-interface methods `protected` is a valid solution for your problem.

Don't care about performance. Programming against interfaces or using access modifiers like public, protected or private has no performance impact.

Comment: making the non-interface methods package private (the default) would also work. No need to make them protected (which allows access from subclasses even outside the package).